# What tags to choose?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, tagging

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this question.

First, how to choose the tags when asking a question? If one does not know which tag to use?

Second, what is the difference between tags that look the same? E.g.,

- elementary-set-theory and set-theory?
- probability and probability-theory?
- riemann-zeta and zeta-functions?
- ...

Now I do not know which tag to use either.

Comment: Reading [tag-wikis](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wikis/info) might help. (Unfortunately, often the tag-wikis are empty.) You can find tag-wiki through the link provided in Michael Greinecker's answer. A shorter *tag-excerpt* is shown to you as a popup when you write a tag into the tag field (when editing the post). They are also shown if you hover above a tag (in a question containing the tag) with your cursor.

Comment: As far as tags for this particular questions (on meta) are concerned, I agree that ([meta-tag:discussion]) and ([meta-tag:support]) are reasonable choices of the tags. But why is this tagged ([meta-tag:feature-request])? I do not see any [feature request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) in the question.

Comment: Having said that I try to follow the descriptions in the tag wikis, I was sometimes in the situation where I was not sure whether choose ([tag:elementary-number-theory]) or ([tag:number-theory]). The same goes for elementary-set-theory vs. set-theory.

Comment: Some advice on choosing reasonable tags is given also in the answer here: [How am I supposed to use tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find descriptions of the tags [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags).