# How do I find the most appropriate tags for my question?

Tags: support, tagging

I feel like I'm usually not finding the right tag to describe what I'm asking.  Is there a list of tags for MSE or something to help me?

Comment: There is a tab "tags" right next to "questions" below the site title... and a search function for tags. (-1) for apparent lack of research.

Comment: There are 53 pages of tags.  Do I simply need to familiarize myself with the vast-but-not-infinite number of tags available?

Comment: That's why there's a search function, as well as the ability to sort by popularity. Unless you're asking an obscure question you can **probably** find a relevant tag on the first page....

Comment: In OP's defence: Their questions are not very easy to tag (I just took a quick look). Not your typical calculus student's questions. Also, props for diagnosing your difficulty rather than just using some braindead method of picking any tag that contains a vaguely familiar word :-)

Comment: Typically an appropriate tag can be found on the cover of the textbook WHEN AT COLLEGE LEVEL (high school not so much). That  may not help you much. And in general it won't help with a more specialized tag. But you can try and search the tags. Or, make your best guess, and ask for suggestions in a comment. I would never, ever give this piece of advice to a high-schooler... algebra? (shudder).

Comment: I'd encourage you to leave a Comment on your Questions asking for help in tag improvements.

Comment: Closely related older question: [How am I supposed to use tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21801) To some extent also: [What tags to choose?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13475)

Comment: For users with [sufficient reputation to talk in chat](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), asking for advice in [the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740) might also be an option.